# .add() explanation

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if anyone can explain me how the jQuery .add() is suppouse to work as I am reading in the jQuery page and trying to understand it and makes no sense to me, I do not understand the utility of it. Lets say I want to add html to all my divs, putting this

```
 $('div').append('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>');
```

makes the job but putting

```
 $('div').add('<p id="new">new paragraph</p>');
```

does not. In the jQuery page http://api.jquery.com/add/ we can read;

> Although the new paragraph has been created and its background color changed, it still does >not appear on the page. To place it on the page, we could add one of the insertion methods to >the chain.

I do not understand why then using add instead of append or another working method. 
Thanks for the time and help.

EDIT

```
$('div#dest').add('p.foo').append('<p id="new">PeNAROL</p>');
```

made me get it, thanks devundef and JamWaffles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) doesn't modify the DOM, it is used to combine 2 matched queries:

```
var queryA = $("a")
var queryB = $("button");

var buttonsAndLinks = queryA.add(queryB);
```

[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is used to append elements into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in [the description](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

> Description: Add elements to the set of matched elements.

`.append()` and `.add()` do *completely* different things.

`.add()` doesn't add an element to the DOM, it adds an element or elements to the set of elements already matched by a previous selector.

For example:

```
$('a.class').add('p.foo');
```

Will return a set of elements containing any `<a class="class">` and `<p class="foo">` elements.

Comment: is pretty clear, i would like to be able to put your answer too as the accepted one as both explanations I got are good, thank you